# is there a quality preset in x264enc?

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I found the default setting of x264enc is very poor. Is there any way to get a good preset for it? I only saw `speed-preset` But this does not affect the quality much. Is there any think like following:

```
Presets:
  "Profile Baseline"
  "Profile High"
  "Profile Main"
  "Profile YouTube"
  "Quality High"
  "Quality Low"
  "Quality Normal"
```

I am using `pass=qual`. The bitrate is used as max value. Is there any good preset can affect this value?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `pass=qual` you should also set the `quantizer` property. Lower values result in higher quality/bitrate. In `pass=qual` the `bitrate` property is ignored.